# library not found for -lReact

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error in all my app builds now and I can't seem to figure it out.

- I *am* using the `.xcworkspace` file
- I had to rename the app. Used: `react-native-app-id ...`
- This morning I was able to build/run on emulator. I tried to setup xcode to run on an actual device and now the universe hates me.
- I can't even `react-native start` and `react-native run-ios` without getting these errors:

  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gmike/Projects/promiscue/tribeoffive/TribeOfFive/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
  ld: library not found for -lReact
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

  ** BUILD FAILED **

  The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tribe-of-five.app/tribe-of-five normal x86_64

  (1 failure)

  Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tribe-of-five.app
  An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
  Failed to install the requested application
  The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
  Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
  Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

  Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/tribe-of-five.app/Info.plist
  Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I've checked out a bunch of other stackoverflow articles.

I think this is telling: 
[image]

Thoughts on how to un-mess up my env?

Answer (score 4):

The error goes away when you remove `libReact.a` from the Xcode file tree (for me, it was under the `Frameworks` folder).

I also removed other files (they all had a transparent/white overlay on them which probably mean they were missing, actually couldn't open them in the finder neither)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for sharing! I had to do the same with the `Libraries` folder

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's resolve this:

### What to look for:

Here's a list of all the sub projects (or their products) that will cause XCode to throw that error when building a react-native project w/ cocoapods:

```
[
RCTActionSheet,
ART,
RCTBlob,
RCTCameraRoll,
RCTGeolocation,
RCTImage,
RCTLinking,
RCTAnimation,
RCTNetwork,
RCTPushNotification,
RCTTest,
RCTSettings,
RCTText,
RCTVibration,
RCTWebSocket,
]
```

### Where to look for those weird project names:

First of all you'll look in the actual error message.
Here's a typical [library not found error](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SudoPlz/0b8eb733a7eacd6476282c0b809c3bd2/raw/308fcadac6cfd0aa4c47daf463992988965f3095/A%2520typical%2520ld:%2520library%2520not%2520found%2520for%2520-lReact%2520clang:%2520error:)

Notice the ... `/libART.a` part?
That fellow is causing that error on my end.

In your case it can be any of the strings in the array above.

### Found the troublemaker, what to do now?

#### Step 1: Remove the troublemaker project.

- Let's try the lucky shot first:

Open the Project Navigator, and check if you can see the linked project that corresponds to the troublemaker string. In my case it was an XCode project called `ART`.
If you find it there, just remove it's reference, and you should be fine.

- If that didn't work:

  Open **{Project Target} > Build Phases** > **Link binary with libraries** and check wether you can see the troublemaker string in there. (It could be something like `libArt.a` depending on what's causing the issue on your end)

If that worked, forget the next step, otherwise move on:

#### Step 2: Delete the derived data directory, clean and rebuild

In my case (as seen in the raw error above) the derived data directory was `/Users/sudoplz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MySuperApp-haxjchilyksewvdfcnnxwrulvyvy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/`

find yours in the error log, and delete it.
You can then clean XCode, shut it down, launch it again, and re-build.

Hopefully that should either fix the issue, or help you move on with fixing other stuff that may have gone wrong.

That's all folks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add that file to the libraries by finding libReact.a from the project, then clean and run Xcode.

or

Try to add libReact.a to your project "Build Phases" > Link binary with libraries, then clean and run Xcode.